# What does type level programming mean at runtime?

Tags: haskell

I am very new to Haskell, so sorry if this is a basic question, or a question founded on shaky understanding

Type level programming is a fascinating idea to me. I think I get the basic premise, but I feel like there is another side to it that is fuzzy to me. I get that the idea is to bring logic and computation into the compiletime instead of runtime, using types. This way you turn what is normally runtime logic/state/data into static logic, e.g. the size of collections.

So I get that for example you can have type level natural numbers, and do type level arithmetic on those natural numbers, and all this calculation and type safety is going on at compile time.

But what does such arithmetic imply at runtime? Especially since Haskell has full type erasure. So for example

- If I concatenate two type level lists, then does the type level safety imply something about the behavior or performance of that concatenation at runtime? Or does the type level programming aspect only have meaning at compile time, when the programmer is grappling the code and putting things together?
- Or if I have two type level numbers, and then multiply them, what does that mean at runtime? If these operations on large numbers are slow at compile time, are they instantaneous at runtime?
- Or if we [implemented type level RSA](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.general/13223) and then use it, what does that even mean at runtime?

Is it purely a compiletime safety/coherence tool? or does type level programming buy us anything for the runtime too? Is the logic and arithmetic 'paid for at compile time' or merely 'assured at compile time' (if that even makes sense)?

Comment: So, this *would* be straightforward to answer, except that it turns out that type-level programming is pretty useless on its own, and so people worked very hard to connect type-level computation with term-level computation. Almost every in-use instance of fancy type-level computation has a parallel term-level computation, computing the same thing, but at runtime...

Comment: In GHC there are a few tools that help maintain the type information at runtime: `Data.Typeable` and `Data.Data`.

Comment: To expand on that, using something like `Typeable` or `Proxy`, you can perform operations using information about that type at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you rightly say, Haskell [without weird extensions] has full type erasure. So that means anything computed purely at the type level is erased at runtime.

However, to do *useful* stuff, you connect the type-level stuff with your value-level stuff to provide useful properties.

Suppose, for example, you want to write a function that takes a pair of lists, treats them as mathematical vectors, and performs a vector dot-product with them. Now the dot-product is only defined on pairs of vectors of *the same size*. So if the size of the vectors doesn't match, you can't return a sensible answer.

Without type-level programming, your options are:

- Require that the caller always supplies vectors of the same dimension, and cheerfully return gibberish if that requirement is not met. (I.e., ignore the problem.)
- Perform an explicit check at run-time, and throw an exception or return `Nothing` or similar if the dimension don't match.

With type-level programming, you can make it so that if the dimensions don't match, *the code does not compile!* So that means *at run-time* you don't need to care about mismatched dimension, because... well, if your code is running, then the dimension *cannot* be mismatched.

The types have all been erased by this point, but you are still guaranteed that your code cannot crash / return gibberish, because the compiler has checked that that cannot happen.

It's really the same as the ordinary checks the compiler does to make sure you don't try to multiply an integer by a string or something. The types are all erased before runtime, and yet the code does not crash.

---

Of course, to do a dot-product, we merely have to check that two numbers are *equal*. We don't need any *arithmetic* yet. But it should be clear that to check whether the dimensions of our vectors match, we need to *know* the dimensions of our vectors. And that means that any operations that change the dimension of our vectors needs to do compile-time calculations, so the compiler can know the result size and check it satisfies the requirements.

You can also do more elaborate stuff. Somewhere I saw a library that lets you define a client/server communications protocol, but because it encodes the protocol into ludicrously complicated type signatures [which the compiler automatically infers], it can statically prove that the client and server implement exactly the same protocol (i.e., no bugs with the server not handling one of the messages the client can send). The types get erased at runtime, but we still know the wire protocol can't go wrong.

Comment: This combined with Daniel Wagner's comment answers my question 

So type programming is strictly a compile time correctness mechanism. It guarantees 'untyped binary blobs interact correctly at runtime' if it is fair to describe it like that. It statically determines which functions and data can work together. But type level computation does not = runtime computation unless the terms are explicitly parallel to the types, in which case no magic ahead-of-time-computing is going on (which i knew didnt make sense, but still felt an intuition reaching for anyway).

Comment: any chance you can dig up that client/server protocol library? sounds interesting even if it is complicated

Comment: I think I found it (the type level client/server protocol library) - https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant